# Get max date and max time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'd like to get the `t.Notes` associated with the `s.SR_Service_RecID` that has the most recent `t.Date_Start` and `t.Time_Start` - As there can be multiple time entries on a single date against a single ticket, I need to include the time as well to get the most recent single result.

```
DECLARE @SD DATETIME,
        @ED DATETIME    

SET     @SD = DATEADD(dd, -14, GETDATE())
SET     @ED = GETDATE()

SELECT s.SR_Service_RecID
     , t.Notes

  FROM SR_Service s
       LEFT JOIN Time_Entry t 
              ON t.SR_Service_RecID = s.SR_Service_RecID

 WHERE s.Date_Closed BETWEEN @SD AND @ED
```

I have tried 2 sub-queries in the WHERE clause, one for the `t.Date_Start` and one for the `t.Time_Start` to only select `MAX` results, but it would limit the results for some reason and there would be missing entries... probably not the right way to go?

```
    AND t.Date_Start IN
        (
            SELECT  MAX(t.Date_Start)
              FROM  Time_Entry t
             WHERE  t.SR_Service_RecID = s.SR_Service_RecID
        )
    AND t.Time_Start IN
        (
            SELECT  MAX(t.Time_Start)
              FROM  Time_Entry t
             WHERE  t.SR_Service_RecID = s.SR_Service_RecID
        )
```

Comment: Could you provide tables definitions and sample data please.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be close.  The mystery is how to combine whatever data types you have for your separate dates and times into a single `DateTime` value.  That's left as an exercise for the OP.

```
select *
  from (
    select s.SR_Service_RecID, t.Notes, t.Date_Start, t.Time_Start,
      Row_Number() over ( partition by s.SR_Service_RecID order by <combined date/time> desc) as [RN]
      from SR_Service as s left outer join
        Time_Entry as t on t.SR_Service_RecID = s.SR_Service_RecID
      where @SD <= s.Date_Closed and s.Date_Closed <= @ED
    ) as Bob
  where RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery with keyword [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189259%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).The WHERE clause of the outer query tests whether the rows that are returned by the subquery exist.

```
SELECT s.SR_Service_RecID, t.Notes
FROM SR_Service s LEFT JOIN Time_Entry t ON t.SR_Service_RecID = s.SR_Service_RecID
WHERE s.Date_Closed BETWEEN @SD AND @ED
 AND EXISTS (
             SELECT 1
             FROM Time_Entry t2
             WHERE s.SR_Service_RecID = t2.SR_Service_RecID
             HAVING MAX(CAST(t2.Date_Start AS datetime) + t2.Time_Start) 
               = CAST(t.Date_Start AS datetime) + t.Time_Start
             )
```